# set encoding as UTF-8 for a FileWriter

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8

Below is my code, it is intended to take two .ckl files, compare the two, add the new items and create a new merged file. The program executes correctly when run in Netbeans however, when executing the .jar the program doesn't appear to be encoding the file in UTF-8. I am rather new to programming and would like to know where or how I might need to be enforcing this encoding to take place?

** I have removed the Swing code and other lines so that only my method is shown, the method that does all of the comparing and merging.

```
public void mergeFiles(File[] files, File mergedFile) {

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    FileWriter fstream = null;
    BufferedWriter out = null;
    try {
        fstream = new FileWriter(mergedFile, false);
        out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
      } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Going in a different direction. We are using a couple booleans to tell us when we want to copy or not. So at the beginning since we start
    // with our source file we set copy to true, we want to copy everything and insert vuln names into our list as we go. After that first file 
    // we set the boolean to false so that we dont start copying anything from the second file until it is a vuln. We set to true when we see vuln
    // and set it to false if we already have that in our list. 
    // We have a tmpCopy to store away the value of copy when we see a vuln, and reset it to that value when we see an </VULN>
    Boolean copy = true;
    Boolean tmpCopy = true;
    for (File f : files) {
        textArea1.append("merging files into: " + mergedFilePathway + "\n");
        FileInputStream fis;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(f);
//                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(mergedFile), "UTF-8"));
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
            String aLine;
            while ((aLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                // Skip the close checklist and we can write it in at the end
                if (aLine.trim().equals("</iSTIG>")) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (aLine.trim().equals("</STIGS>")) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (aLine.trim().equals("</CHECKLIST>")) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (aLine.trim().equals("<VULN>")) {
                    // Store our current value of copy
                    tmpCopy = copy;
                    copy = true;
                    String aLine2 = in.readLine();
                    String aLine3 = in.readLine();
                    String nameLine = in.readLine();

                    if (list.contains(nameLine.trim())) {
                        textArea1.append("Skipping: " + nameLine + "\n");
                        copy = false;
                        while (!(aLine.trim().equals("</VULN>"))) {
                            aLine = in.readLine();
                        }
                        continue; // this would skip the writing out to file part
                    } else {
                        list.add(nameLine.trim());
                        textArea1.append("::: List is now :::");
                        textArea1.append(list.toString() + "\n");
                    }
                    if (copy) {
                        out.write(aLine);
                        out.newLine();
                        out.write(aLine2);
                        out.newLine();
                        out.write(aLine3);
                        out.newLine();
                        out.write(nameLine);
                        out.newLine();
                    }
                } else if (copy) {
                    out.write(aLine);
                    out.newLine();
                }
                // after we have written to file, if the line was a close vuln, switch copy back to original value
                if (aLine.trim().equals("</VULN>")) {
                    copy = tmpCopy;
                }
            }

            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        copy = false;
    }

    // Now lets add the close checklist tag we omitted before
    try {
        out.write("</iSTIG>");
        out.write("</STIGS>");
        out.write("</CHECKLIST>");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code.  Please edit your question and remove all the Swing code, as it's not relevant to your question.  I'm pretty sure only the `mergeFiles` method is relevant.

Comment: Thank you, I have deleted the code that didn't seem necessary. We are now left with the method that compares and merges.

Comment: You have removed too much.  The entire mergeFiles method needs to be in your question, especially the line of code which creates `out`, as that's likely to be the cause of your problem.

Comment: I apologize, I did not realize I had deleted so much. The entire mergeFiles method is shown now.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Java has [extensive, highly informative documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/).  Keep it bookmarked.  Refer to it first, whenever you have difficulty.  You'll find it's frequently helpful.

In this case, the [documentation for FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) says:

> The constructors of this class assume that the default character encoding and the default byte-buffer size are acceptable. To specify these values yourself, construct an OutputStreamWriter on a FileOutputStream.

If you want to be sure your file will be written as UTF-8, replace this:

```
FileWriter fstream = null;
BufferedWriter out = null;
try {
    fstream = new FileWriter(mergedFile, false);
```

with this:

```
Writer fstream = null;
BufferedWriter out = null;
try {
    fstream = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(mergedFile), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Answer (score 21):

For those, who use `FileWriter` in order to append to an existing file, the following will work

```
try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file, true), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {

    //code

}
```

Comment: Actually, this seems like a valid answer given that you're focusing on the append situation, and as such I don't think should be posted as a comment.  In the future, wait until you have reputation to comment.  Answers that are comments just get deleted

Comment: This construction should be avoided, preferring `try (FileOutputStream fos = ...; OutputStreamWriter osw = ...(fos); BufferWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osw)) {`. Otherwise the intermediate objects won't have `close()` called on them if an exception occurs in a subsequently executed constructor. For example if the `BufferedWriter()` has an exception (highly unlikely in this particular case), the `OutputStreamWriter` and `FileOutputStream` instances won't have `close()` called. See [Java 8 JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3.1).

Comment: @neuralmer -- Excellent point.Attempting to paraphrase -- when we have a nested wrapping of `AutoCloseable` resource objects (here `BufferedReader` wraps `OutputStreamWriter` which wraps `FileOutputStream`), rather than have a *try-with-one-resource* statement on just the outermost wrapper object, it is preferable to have a *try-with-multiple-resources* statement, and then break the nested instantiation.into multiple separate resource-initialization statements of the *try* clause. There. Phew. That was a mouthful from me. I'm sure your eyes would have glazed over. :-)

Answer (score 7):

You can just run it with the command `java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -jar yourjar.jar`.

Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/623036/2015911) for more info.